# How to delete rows from a table by another table with a special condition?

Tags: sql, sql-delete

If I have those two tables:

Planet(Name,size)

Moon(Name, PlanetName*)

How can I delete planets that have more than 3 moons? I not sure if my answer is correct or not

```
DELETE Name
FROM Planet
INNER JOIN Moon WHERE Moon >3
```

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is not correct.  The planets that have more than three moons are given by:

```
select planetname
from moon
group by panetname
having count(*) > 3;
```

You can then delete the planets using `in` or `exists`:

```
delete from planet
    where planetname in (select planetname
                         from moon
                         group by planetname
                         having count(*) > 3
                        );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from planets where 
    (select count(*) from moon where moon.planetname = planet.name) > 3
```

or

```
delete from planets where 
    exists(select count(*) from moon 
           where moon.planetname = planet.name 
           group by planetname  -- you may not need that, because for each row they are all equal, due to the where condition
           having count(*) > 3
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong ! because your query donot mention the count .

Try this query

```
DELETE from planets
     WHERE
       Name = ((SELECT   COUNT(*)  
                FROM     moon 
                WHERE    moon.planetname = planet.name) > 3 )
```